# PHP Initializing a new instance of a subclass from a parent static method?

Tags: php

How would I initialize a subclass from a parent static method?

I could get subclass's static variable using late static binding in PHP 5.3 and the `static` keyword in a parent class's methods. How would I initialize a new instance of a subclass in a parent **static** method?

Thanks.

Comment: There are design pattern well known for that kind of things, please be a little bit more precise: what **result** are you trying to get? Why do you want to do that? We can then guide you to the right design pattern.

Comment: .. or, for those of us not obsessed with stringent "design patterns", we can guide you to the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to involve static variables or anything that messy.  Here's the shortest example I can come up with:

```
class a {
    public static function foo() { return new static; }
}

class b extends a { }
```

if you call `b::foo()` you will get a new b.